# How to overwrite part of a vector?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, overwrite

I am trying to rewrite part of a vector given that:
    t = -10:.1:10
    x = exp((-3.*t);
The length of `x` will be 201, and I want to rewrite the first 100 values.
The only way I've gotten to work is by doing this:

**EDIT** Fixed typo.

```
t = 0:.1:10;
x = exp((-3.*t); % EDIT: THERE WAS A TYPO HERE
z = zeros(1,100);
for k = 1 : 100
x(k) = z(k);
end
```

There are three questions. First: What is a faster and more efficient way of doing this? Second: What do I do if I don't want to overwrite the first part of the code but rather the middle or the second part? Third: Is there a way of utilizing the full range of `t` where `t = -10:.1:10` and just ignoring the first half instead of writing a whole new variable for it?

First: Nothing else I've tried has been successful.

Second: The only way I can think to do that is to append the two vectors together, but then it doesn't overwrite the data, so that is a no go.

Third:I have tried an if statement and that didn't work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code appears to assign something to `y`, then changes the value of `x`. I assume that is a typo - and not the problem you actually want to fix.

In general, if you have

```
t = -10:0.1:10;  % my preference: t = linspace(-10,10,201);
```

and

```
y = exp(-3 * t );
```

but you want to set the first 100 elements of y to zero, you can then do

```
y(1:100) = 0;
```

If you wanted never to compute y(1:100) in the first place you might do

```
y = zeros(size(t));
y(101:end) = exp(-3 * t(101:end));
```

There are many variations on this. I think the above code samples address all three of your questions.

Comment: I don't agree that `linspace` is necessarily the better way to go. In the first case (`10:0.1:10`) it is very clear what the spacing is going to be between each value. I have seen far too many people try to replicate this with linspace and used `linspace(-10,10,200)` instead. Also, if you actually benchmark it, linspace is significantly slower than the first method.

Comment: @MrAzzaman thanks for your comment. I said "better" only because you can control "for sure" how many samples you will have, and that they are equally spaced. It avoids problems like `-1:0.3:1` not ending at `1`. I agree each has strengths and weaknesses - but I usually care more about "first and last element". I probably overstated that it was "better". I should say "I prefer".

Answer (score 1):

You could use logical indexing; that is, you can use a logical statement to select elements of a vector/matrix:

```
t = -10:0.1:10;
x = exp((-3.*t);
x(t < 0) = 0;
```

This works for the middle of a matrix too:

```
x(t > -5 & t < 5) = whatever;
```

Answer (score 1):

change your

```
for k = 1 : 100
  x(k) = z(k);  % i think it should be y(k) though
end
```

to

```
x(1:100) = 0;
```